Why does WhatsApp use two constants (0x0600 and 0x0601) for signing linking metadata between primary and companion devices?
In WhatsApp, two types of devices can be connected to an account: the primary device (a mobile) and a companion device (connected through the primary device). To indicate that both devices are linked to the account, the primary device creates linking metadata (LM) and signs (0x0600 || LM) with its private key. The companion device signs (0x0601 || LM || primary's public key) with its private key. Why does WhatsApp use the two constants (0x0600 and 0x0601) in this process?

When using the same signing key for multiple purposes or signing things of different structure, it's sound and common practice to always start what's signed with a unique constant identifying the purpose and/or structure of what's signed. That prevents adversaries from passing a signature intended for one purpose as one intended for another purpose. Also that helps for interoperability between different versions.
My guess is that's a big part of the rationale. 0x0600 is for signing LM, 0x0601 is for signing "LM || primary's public key", whatever that is.
